Update default values in react-form-hook
I'm using react hook form like this:

export function UpdateTeacherForm({ user }: { user: User }) {
  const {
    register,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid },
  } = useForm<UpdateTeacherSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(updateTeacherSchema),
    mode: 'all',
    defaultValues: {
      avatar: user.avatar ? toUploaderFile(user.avatar) : undefined,
      video: user.video ? toUploaderFile(user.video) : undefined,
      description: user.description,
      phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    reset({
      avatar: user.avatar ? toUploaderFile(user.avatar) : undefined,
      video: user.video ? toUploaderFile(user.video) : undefined,
      description: user.description,
      phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
    });
  }, [user]);

The thing is that user property is initially very small (comes from token) and then it is updated from server. That's why I'm using useEffect hook with reset. However, I want to avoid using that approach and instead update defaultaValues. Now even though new user comes as a prop, default values are not updated. Any suggestions why?

You can use async to set the default value rather than resetting it in useEffect.Below is the code snippet that i have coppied from the react hook form documentation itself.
useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  }
})

// set default value async
useForm({
  defaultValues: async () => fetch('/api-endpoint');
})


Also, based on documentation, you should avoid the usage of undefined for the default values.
